# Trying to pass an object's variable into another method

Tags: c#

Hey I'm very very new to c# coding and OOP, I'm currently working on a system that allows users to create login details, and then login with said details, however when I get to the part where I verify the users details I am having issues getting it to recognize my object, AccName, credentialCheck() can't successfully get the information from accountCreation(), I know this is a very basic thing to know but I have tried so many things and none of them have worked, or I haven't been doing them properly. My code is shown below and any guidance that could be provided would be greatly appreciated.

```
static void accountCreation()
{
    Console.Write("Username: ");
    string userNameInput = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Write("Email: ");
    string userEmailInput = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Write("Password: ");
    string userPasswordInput = Console.ReadLine();

    Account AccName = new Account($"{userNameInput}", $"{userEmailInput}", $"{userPasswordInput}");
    Console.Write($"{userNameInput} Registered successfully");
    Console.WriteLine();
}
static void credentialCheck()
{
    Console.Write("Email: ");
    string userEmailCheck = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Write("Password: ");
    string userPasswordCheck = Console.ReadLine();
    if (userEmailCheck == AccName.userEmail )
    {
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Success");
    }
```

Comment: `AccName` is a _local variable_ in `accountCreation` - it's gone as soon as the method returns. You need to persist the `Account` object somewhere (like, in a database) if you want to use it later

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are calling `credentialCheck()` just after `accountCreation()` and in the same thread. That out of the way, I supposed you have `accName` as a static variable and your class overall looks like this:

```cs
class Login {
  protected static Account accName;

  static void accountCreation()
  {
    // ...
    accName = new Account(userNameInput, userEmailInput, userPasswordInput);
  }
}
```

This means the variable `accName` remains as far as the execution context is concerned and not immediately destroyed after `accountCreation()` returns.